# mod_rewrite's redirect problems with www domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Trying to configure .htaccess mod_rewrite rules for redirecting page
http://www.example.com/page1/ to http://www.example.com/page2/.

Valuable .htaccess rules for this is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?page1/?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/page2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?s_page=$1 [L]
```

This rule works correct if I send get query: "GET http://example.com/page1/".

But if I try to write additional rule for domain www.example.com such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?page1/?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/page2/ [R=301,L]
```

Redirect doesn't work correctly. If I try send query: "GET http://www.example.com/page1/" then, at first, browser sends first query "GET http://www.example.com/page1/" and server's answer status is "301 Moved Permanently" for this query (and html page is sended by server as answer to the first query). Then, browser sends second query "GET http://www.example.com/page2/" (and html page is sended again by the server).
I need that conditions and rules works similarly for query with domain with www and query without domain's www prefix.

PS. sorry for english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a new rule for `www` domain. Just tweak the regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^page1/?$ http://www.example.com/page2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?s_page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes, it's more compact format and works similar. But, similar, when i type "http://www.example.com/page1" in browser, it sends two GET queries, first "GET http://www.example.com/page1" with answer headers:
`"Cache-Control max-age=0
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 243
Content-Type text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date Tue, 13 Jan 2015 14:50:50 GMT
Expires Tue, 13 Jan 2015 14:50:50 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5
Location http://www.example.com/page2/
Server Apache`
" and body's is requested html page content.
Then, browser send's second query as i wrote earlier.

Comment: Hmm... maybe it is correct redirect work? I think than only one query should sended by browser and only one page content should be retrieved from server.

Comment: `http://www.example.com/page1` will be redirected using `R=301` to `http://www.example.com/page2`. So yes browser will make 2 GET requests if you're trying to open `http://www.example.com/page1`. However if you visit `http://www.example.com/page2` it should be just single GET request in browser.